# Disk Space on Home partition shrinks from 5.5GB to 0 after each restart

Tags: disk, disk-usage

My disk space "vanishes" after in a couple minutes after strating my system. I have a 11 GB home partition and actually only appr. 5 GB are used according to du. df though shows 0 bytes free? My system cannot save any file in the home directory thus it becomes unuseable. Any solution approaches? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check you remaining free inodes with `df -ih`. If you use many small files (such as on a mailserver) then you may have run out! This is unlikely on a desktop, but let's eliminate it as a possibility first.